# Array of similar names and numbers into ranged groups

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

I have an array that looks like this:

```
["mac1", "mac2", "mac3", "win1", "win2", "win3", "tablet1", "tablet2", "tablet3", "tablet5"]
```

How can I group the values with similar names into a range that looks like this?

```
["mac1-3", "win1-3", "tablet1-3", "tablet5"]
```

Please note that the numbers are not always consecutive (check "tablet" values)

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that the numbers are consecutive? What happens, for example, if `"mac2"` is missing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We tend to prefer it if you've had a go at it yourself - then show us where you got to - even if it's not working. Then we help you to figure out a way past the bit that's stopping you. This, rather than asking us to do it all for you :) So - what do you think you'd try first to get this working?

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I will definitely consider that next time I post on stackoverflow. It's true that for this question I didn't think much, because I didn't even know where to start from.

Comment: Sawa - good questionn! Actually the numbers are not guaranteed to be consecutive and the similar names may not even appear one after the other.

Comment: Sawa - If "mac2" is missing then I'd expect a result like this ["mac1", "mac3", "win1-3"]

Comment: @sylvian Can you please click "edit" and add the new information to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

**Code**

```
def group_em(arr)
  arr.map { |w| [w[/[a-z]+/i], w[/\d+/].to_i] }
     .sort
     .slice_when { |(e1,n1),(e2,n2)| (e1 != e2) || n2 > n1+1 }
     .map do |arr|
        s = "#{arr.first.first}#{arr.first.last}"
        (arr.size>1) ? (s << "-#{arr.last.last}") : s
      end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["tablet2", "win2", "tablet3", "win1", "win3", "mac1",
       "tablet99", "mac3", "mac2", "tablet1"] 
group_em(arr)
  #=> ["mac1-3", "tablet1-3", "tablet99", "win1-3"]
```

**Explanation**

```
a = arr.map { |w| [w[/[a-z]+/i], w[/\d+/].to_i] }.sort
  #=> [["mac", 1], ["mac", 2], ["mac", 3], ["tablet", 1], ["tablet", 2],
  #    ["tablet", 3], ["tablet", 99], ["win", 1], ["win", 2], ["win", 3]]
```

Slice using [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (introduced in v.2.2):

```
e = a.slice_when { |(e1,n1),(e2,n2)| (e1 != e2) || n2 > n1+1 }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ffb1c8547a0>:each>
```

We can see the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[["mac", 1], ["mac", 2], ["mac", 3]],
  #    [["tablet", 1], ["tablet", 2], ["tablet", 3]],
  #    [["tablet", 99]],
  #    [["win", 1], ["win", 2], ["win", 3]]]
```

Lastly:

```
e.map do |arr|
  s = "#{arr.first.first}#{arr.first.last}"
  (arr.size>1) ? (s << "-#{arr.last.last}") : s
end
  #=> ["mac1-3", "tablet1-3", "tablet99", "win1-3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the numbers are consecutive:

```
["mac1", "mac2", "mac3", "win1", "win2", "win3"] 
.group_by{|e| e[/\D+/]}
.map{|k, v| k + v.map{|s| s[/\d+/].to_i}.minmax.join("-")}
# => ["mac1-3", "win1-3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no break between the numbers (i.e. 2 exists if we have values 1 and 3)

```
input = ["mac1", "mac2", "mac3", "win1", "win2", "win3"]
h = input.each_with_object({}) do |i, h|
  m = i.match(/(.*?)(\d+)/)
  fst = m[1]
  snd = m[2].to_i

  h[fst] = [] if h[fst].nil?
  h[fst] << snd
end

output = h.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), a|
  a << "#{k}#{v.min}-#{v.max}"
end

puts output  # outputs ["mac1-3", "win1-3"]
```

Comment: Try this with `input = ["mac9", "mac10"]`.

Comment: Thanks - fixed with non-greedy `(.*)` and matched multiple digits.